# How to sort the system calls by frequency generated by the perf command?

Tags: performance-monitoring

I have collected the perf syscall events using the perf tool by executing the command

```
perf record -F 99 -e 'syscalls:*' -p <pid>
```

The **perf report** command displays the system calls and its frequency but it does not sort by the frequency. The man page also not of help. How to sort the syscalls by frequency?

Comment: If you provide an example of the output, we might be able to assist better. I'm thinking of combining `awk` and `sort` to get the desired result.

Comment: The binary data of the perf outuput is recored in perf.data file that is usually viewed with "perf report" tool which is interactive console application. Althought piping the "perf report | cat" prints output to the terminal, that output has some processing info and also entirely different output tformat hat that is being viewed in interactive mode.  i am really not sure the right thing way to use "perf report" is by piping and then sorting using text processing tools. Can some one confirm if this a normal use of "perf report" ?